# Can google.script.run.withSuccessHandler return area?

Tags: javascript, html

i call a function (named here xx1) and i want to return an area variable. But it return undefined.
Here is my code

```
//in html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="e1" name="e1" value="aaa">
<input id="e2" name="e2" value="aaa">
<input id="e3" name="e3" value="aaa">
</form>

<script>

function bb(ff){
document.getElementById("e1").value=ff["e1"];
document.getElementById("e2").value=ff["e2"];
document.getElementById("e3").value=ff["e3"];
M.updateTextFields();
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(bb)
      .xx1();
</script>
</body>
</html>

//in code.gs
function xx1(){
var pp=[];
var obj={};
obj.e1="e1 hh";
obj.e2="e2 hh";
obj.e3="e2 hh";
pp.push[obj];
return pp;
}
```

Why i can't recover the area returned by the function xx1()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.push` is a function but you are using index access. `pp.push[obj];` should be `pp.push(obj)`

```js
const x1 = () => {
  var pp=[];
  var obj={};
  obj.e1="e1 hh";
  obj.e2="e2 hh";
  obj.e3="e2 hh";
  pp.push[obj];
  return pp;
}

const x2 = () => {
  var pp=[];
  var obj={};
  obj.e1="e1 hh";
  obj.e2="e2 hh";
  obj.e3="e2 hh";
  pp.push(obj);
  return pp;
}

console.log ({x1: x1(), x2: x2()})
```